# Acumatica: Report Design Different When Printed

Tags: acumatica

I noticed that the report's designs preview and printed are different.
I found it that all of the reports are the same.
So I tried to create new test report and notice that background colors are not rendered on print.
How too keep the design when printing?

Design:
[image]
+++

Printed:
[image]

Comment: Are you comparing the preview in Acumatica ERP and the result of printing from Browser?

Comment: As a general rule only PDF guarantees accurate rendering. The report engine can render to HTML and PDF. HTML rendering is notoriously inaccurate and results  will vary wildly depending on browser/versions css etc.. That being said maybe your issue is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Reports are rendered in HTML mode. As is often the case with HTML, the report as seen in the browser uses a different CSS style then the one sent to the browser print dialog. I'm pretty sure the reason for this is to accommodate printer technology. Printing  solid dark backgrounds uses up a lot of ink and text is more legible when it's black text over a white background.

With HTML rendering, browser view and print preview differ to accommodate printer limitations:
[image]

HTML was never meant for accurate rendering anyway so I think the CSS change is for the better but if you want exact result just switch to PDF mode which is meant to provide accurate rendering. Print preview should match very closely the PDF rendering in browser when the report is displayed in PDF mode:
[image]

It can get tiring to manually switch to PDF each time by clicking the rendering mode button so you can change the default mode in the report configuration:
[image]

It is also possible to edit your custom reports or the standard ones so they default to PDF rendering in the browser instead of the current HTML default:
[image]

To edit report you will need to install Acumatica Report Designer (it is in Acumatica ERP Windows Installer) and use the EDIT REPORT button and then use Save to Server file menu item in the report designer to save the report modifications:
[image]

Comment: Wow! Thank you for multiple options to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the **Background Graphics** checkbox in the printing dialog of your printing preview program? It's primarily in the **More Settings** section.
Please find below example for Google Chrome's dialog:
[image]

Comment: Thank you. I'll prefer HB_ACUMATICA's answer for universality and one time configurations.