# How do you embed images into Acumatica Report hyperlinks?

Tags: acumatica

We are trying to incorporate an image within a link on an Acumatica report.
We are very close to getting the result we need with the 2018R2 version and have a strategy for a workaround in the 2018R1 version.

The TextBox control Is the only way we have found so far that will allow for setting a hyperlink within an invoice report definition. We are able to set a background image in the Appearance/Style/BackImage property. The only way we can get the whole image to be clickable is to have text span the whole control which is fine if we can set the text font to use a transparent color. Setting the Appearance/Style/Color seems to be the property to do this however when the report is previewed the font gets overridden and displayed as the standard Hyperlink color. The behavior when the report is rendered as a PDF via Acumatica’s email delivery system the font appears white. See Images for a visual.

Transparent Text in Report Preview

[image: Transparent Text in Report Preview]

Transparent Text in Rendered PDF

[image: Transparent Text in Rendered PDF]

There looks to be an Appearance/StyleName property for the TextBox control is there an underlying CSS file that can be further manipulated to also control the LinkText properties to display the LinkText in a transparent font? If yes is there any documentation that would help with doing this. 
The 2018R1 versions and prior do not render a clickable link within a PDF if the above strategy is used. Per the ticket, I opened last week on the topic the only way to get this link is to have the whole URL on a single line. 
[PDFs rendered from a invoice definition hosting a hyperlink will not create a clickable link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55165630/pdfs-rendered-from-a-invoice-definition-hosting-a-hyperlink-will-not-create-a-cl/55167131?noredirect=1#comment97076246_55167131)
This makes it a challenge to control the placement of the image to be centered as well as having only the space within the first line as being clickable. We have solved this in a different ERP system by having multiple links overlapping a background image also using transparent font. This required us to set the Z order so that the link controls are rendered on top of the back-ground image. The Acumatica Report Designer however appears to not have the ability to control Z order. Any attempt to place a link overtop of an image does not achieve the result we are looking for. If we can get this strategy to work we will likely also use it for the 2018R2+ versions to keep things consistent.

This screenshot depicts the strategy attempted.
[image: Placing Transparent Text over top of image]

Are there any other strategies to meet this requirement?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The template "TemplateForm.rpx" is not CSS and is a template for report designer properties. It's mainly used to set default Style in Appearance->Style. It can't do anything more than what you can do on UI so is not useful here.

Comment: I posted an answer for both versions, 2018 R2 it works out of the box for PDF mode. For 2018 R1 I wasn't able to find a workaround that renders transparent text over an image.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I got sideswiped with something else. I'm going to try you're answer now. As for the R1 issue is it plausible to use HTML such as 
    <a href="http://www.google.com">
        <img src="data:image/jpeg;{Base64StringForImage}"/>
    </a>

Comment: I don't think report designer supports HTML tags like that because PDF engine can't render that: https://feedback.acumatica.com/ideas/ACU-I-920

Comment: My answer works only for 2018 R2 in PDF. I think it kinda works in HTML but the image isn't showing, presumably this is because the HTML CSS hides background images.

Comment: I don't think the reason you're looking at HTML is to embed the image in the report but if that's the case in the Report Designer property editor, you can select the Report object and use the EmbeddedImages property of the Data section.

Comment: I'm actively using EmbeddedImages with what I have so far. I was thinking that HTML might be a candidate to work around the issues pointed out. I have the HTML in the Email Notification Template and that is working like a charm. I think we are going to have to live with it but would like to follow up by sending a formal enhancement request to add support for Image Links in the future that will work for both PDF and in Report Preview. What is the best way to submit that request?

Answer (score 0):

**For Version 2018 R2:**

You can use the `TextBox->Style->BackImage` property to show the image and the `NavigateUrl` property to set the URL link. Html mode doesn't display back image but PDF mode will display it fine and the image link works:

[image]

**For Version 2018 R1:**

Unfortunately I didn't find a way to achieve this because I can't get the text to render transparent when it is located over an image.

There is z-order control (bring to front/send to back) in the report designer toolbar and right click context-menu. The problem here is that while the report designer supports overlapping control the report renderer doesn't. If controls are overlapping, when printing the report the overlapping controls won't get rendered on top of another like they are in the designer.

Having overlapping controls isn't really required here because we can display the image with the Textbox Style->BackImage property or with the Report->Style->BackImage.

It's also possible to make text font size bigger so you don't need multiple text box or set multiline=true with textwrap=false and repeat link on each line.

But the main issue remains rendering transparent text over an image. I couldn't find a way to do that. When there's an image under the text, the text is no longer transparent. That behavior happens for the textbox background image as well as the global report background image. This suggests to me that it might not be possible to put transparent text on top:

[image]

Comment: this almost worked. When the Value field is left empty the PDF that is rendered is indeed clickable. However, when the report is viewed within the preview mode the image is not clickable with no text within the control. We want this link clickable within the Customer Self Service Portal so this option is not going to work in that context. The client might need to live with having had the link as text. Thanks for your help with this.

Comment: Preview mode in PDF works for me, preview mode in HTML won't show background image. It can't be both an image and text link at the same time, at best it will overlap. In 2018 R2 you use NavigateURL for the link URL and Value for the text link description.

Comment: By preivew, I am referring to this screen. I dont believe the PDF is rendered in this screen. https://www.dropbox.com/s/smqmkegu5d3yjtn/2019-03-20_12-20-18.jpg?dl=0

Comment: this is the control setup https://www.dropbox.com/s/dqo8ng35slxot7n/2019-03-20_12-27-50.jpg?dl=0

Comment: The Dropbox link seems to be restricted and cannot be seen by anyone other than those you allowed

Comment: Can you let me know if these links work? I moved them to another folder that should not be restricted. Preview Screen https://www.dropbox.com/s/smqmkegu5d3yjtn/2019-03-20_12-20-18.jpg?dl=0 Control setup https://www.dropbox.com/s/dqo8ng35slxot7n/2019-03-20_12-27-50.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Still looks like it's not accessible, try logging off from dropbox and accessing it or simply try in "incognito/private" mode of your browser.

Comment: These Links seem to work in incognito mode. I think I saved the originals to a restricted folder and the metadata moved with it when I moved the files. https://www.dropbox.com/s/k8uh75ca79qw0t4/PreviewPage.jpg?dl=0  https://www.dropbox.com/s/7zymek1hg3prle3/ControlSetup.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Yeah I can see them, on first screenshot "PreviewPage.jpg" Just below Invoice/Memo title text I see in the toolbar that the third icon is a PDF icon. This tells me preview mode is in HTML. Can you try clicking on PDF to see if image are displayed? I know they wont in HTML preview but they should in PDF preview. Instead of clicking on the toolbar button you can also go to the report page where you edit it, in one of the preference tab you can make it so it always default to PDF in preview mode.

Comment: When I open them in PDF preview mode using the icon you pointed out the link indeed works. The image does show in the previous mode it just not clickable. Im going to look into the preference setting you pointed out. Hopefully, there is a way for an administrator to turn that on for the whole system. I will check into it.

Comment: Awesome!!! I found the setting you pointed out. For those following along it is found by selecting the whole report object while in Acumatica Report Designer. The property you are looking for is Behavior/CommonSettings/ViewPdf. set this to true and the report will always display in PDF preview mode.

Comment: There are multiple default to PDF setting. I've listed them all in this previous answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54814005/7376238

Comment: I meant changing in Acumatica page from where you can edit the report not in the report designer itself. But doing it in Report Designer works too and might be the best way to apply the default as widely as possible.

Comment: Thanks, defaulting as widely as possible is favorable. I think that is going to do the job.